# Excel to Word, Long Date Writing To Upper Case Automatically

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating a Macro in VBA to find and replace some words in a Word doc. However, the code is putting the dates in the word.doc in upper case and I want it low case. Could you please help? I have the date in the excel file in DD/MM/YY format and I want it in Long Date format

```
Sub test_date()    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document    
    Dim wdRng As Word.Range
    Dim w_data As Worksheet

    Set w_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\*******")

    For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges
        With wdRng.Find
            .Text = "D_H"
            .Replacement.Text = WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-pt-PT]dd ""de"" mmmm ""de"" yyyy")
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

            .Text = "D_VL"
            .Replacement.Text = WorksheetFunction.Text(w_data.Range("C9"), "[$-pt-PT]dd ""de"" mmmm ""de"" yyyy")

            .Wrap = wdFindContinue    
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing
    Next wdRng
    MsgBox ("test finished")  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the range in Word is not formatted using "All Caps"? If it is, this is what needs to be changed...

Comment: @CindyMeister, it was exactly that! thank you!